# SharePoint development in visual studio without having to deploy/debug on every code changes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using VS2010 connected to a local SP2010 installation, I edit the code in VS2010 (i.e. of a WebPart) and then in order to see the result on a browser I deploy the solution.

This is very annoying since it is a big project and it takes a couple of mins to deploy the solution.

I was wondering if it is possible to have the "edit -> save -> F5" approach even for SharePoint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm gonna to integrate here the answer i get from the kind ppl and what i've actually done to solve/mitigate my slowness problem:

- Installed CKSDev Visual Studio plugin from here: http://cksdev.codeplex.com/
- On the SharePoint project properties tab set to 'True' the property 'Auto copy to SharePoint root', with that on each time you do save a 'visual' (ascx, aspx, js, css, ..) source file, it will be automatically copied over the SP hive without having to manually push it using the Quick Depl. option
  [image: project properties]
- On SharePoint project properties page (right-click, properties), add the following post build event command line:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\gacutil.exe"  /i "$(TargetPath)"
>
> iisreset

The previous commands will:

1. Install the project dlls into the GAC
2. Restart IIS in order to catch the new dlls

Now each time you do save a change in the visual or build the code it will automatically pushed to the SP installation.

For newer source files i still need to normally deploy the project.

Comment: Glad that you've found a solution to your problem, but restarting the IIS is an overkill.
Try recycling your application pools instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by copying the modified file to the corresponding folder inside SharePoint Hive[14] (Or you can edit it there directly), and recycle the application pool.

Note that it this solution is only applicable to web parts, pages and xml files and it cannot be done for code files.

If you have modified your code files you have to recompile them and copy the dlls to GAC[%systemroot%\assembly] or BIN[14\bin] folder depending on your settings.

Comment: thanks for the answer, thats exactly what i had fear of :( right now i'm editing the visual part directly into SP hive than copy the change back into VS in order to commit changes, but i can't do that for C# code

Comment: Well, you could use WSP builder to ease this process, but if your projects takes more than a minute to deploy then I guess it is not applicable for you to use it.

Comment: @Jigs and Mhd. Yasseen thanks both for the suggestion, i wasn't aware of CKSdev tool, it is very handy!

Answer (score 1):

Download CKS: Development Tools Edition (aka CKSDev) from [here](http://cksdev.codeplex.com) and install into VS 2010. You will see new context menu "Quick Deploy" in solution manager which will speed up requested tasks: deploy to GAC/BIN, Recycle App Pool and more (shortcuts are accessible!). Very handy tool.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'm using it and seems that in my case the only "Quick Deploy" option that actually works is "Copy to SharePoint Root" since the GAC copy is copying the solution dll in the SharePoint hive instead of the GAC itself, i'm gonna answer the question in order to integrate your suggestion and what i've actually performed

Answer (score 1):

Use CKSDev, and separate your solution into smaller solutions so you can work on a subset of your projects, I would be very surprised if your webpart is dependent on every project in your master solution. If you are developing on a virtual machine without internet access also ensure that you are not waiting for timeout on your certification checks everytime you recycle the apppool (happens when you deploy). Read here for how to: http://joelblogs.co.uk/2011/09/20/certificate-revocation-list-check-and-sharepoint-2010-without-an-internet-connection/

Comment: Yep i agree, each webparts are not dependant from the other projects but i see that when i use the normal deploy feature the waste of time is on: deactivate features, retract solution, delete solution, delete custom pages, and then install everything back again

Answer (score 0):

I am going though below step during debug code.

1)  if you are changes only code assembly than Build Your Project after changes code.

2) Open `Assembly` folder(run > assembly) and drag and drop your project's dll(will be found it out from Your Project Directory\bin\Debug).

3) open `IIS` (run > inetmgr) and goto `Application Pools` and find it out your sharepoint we-app's Pool. after selecting Application Pool `(Recycle)` it.

4) now come back on `VS SharePoint Project`.Debug > Attach to Process > [w3wp.exe](http://adotnetdude.blogspot.in/2010/05/visual-studio-2010-debugger-not.html#comment-form).

should be hit your break point.

that's it.